# C++11: Standard ref for action of `auto` on const and reference types

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a type T:

```
typedef ... T;
```

and then I have these functions:

```
T f11();
T& f12();
T&& f13();
const T f21();
const T& f22();
const T&& f23();
```

and then call them like this:

```
auto x11 = f11();
auto x12 = f12();
auto x13 = f13();
auto x21 = f21();
auto x22 = f22();
auto x23 = f23();
```

From which sections/clauses of the C++11 standard can it be deduced the equivalent non-auto declarations of x11..x23?

Comment: Now hold on. `typedef ... T;` makes any normal compiler spits out compilation errors

Comment: @BЈовић: `...` in this context is a placeholder for any valid type.  (not helped by the fact that `...` is also valid C++ in some places)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in §7.1.6.4 **auto specifier**. In your examples of function return types, the rules of template argument deduction apply.

Paraquoting the relevant example from the standard:

> `const auto &i = expr;`
>
> The type of `i` is the deduced type of the parameter X in the call `f(expr)` of the following invented function template:
>
> `template <class AUTO> void f(const AUTO& X);`

So in your examples, the types of all your variables `x11` to `x23` are deduced as `T`.

Comment: That is if `template<typename T> g(T t);` than `g(f())` and `auto t = f()` would result in the same type of t in both cases?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling the example in the standard is `const auto&i = expr` and `template <class U> void f(const U& u);`. Here, the type of `i` is the deduced type of `u` in `f(expr)`.

Comment: In particular, this means that the type of each deduced variable will be `T`.

Comment: Maybe you should have written `template <class AUTO>` to make the point... :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I have adopted your suggestion. I wasn't to keen on modifying a quote from the standard until I discovered "paraquote".