# Automatic type deduction and auto&& vs auto

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, type-deduction

I just watched Scott Meyers [Universal References in C++11](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) and there was one thing I could not quite understand.

I am a bit confused as to what the difference is between a `auto` as a "universal reference", i.e. `auto&&` and a regular `auto`, when do they differ?

```
Foo f;
Foo& lvr = f;

auto lvr_a = f; // Foo&
auto rvr_a = std::move(f); // Foo&& or is it Foo?

auto&& lvr_b = f; // Foo& && => Foo&
auto&& lvr_b = std::move(f); // Foo&& && => Foo&&
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auto will decay to the value type (ie take a copy with copy constructor), whereas auto&& will preserve the reference type.

See here: [C++11: Standard ref for action of `auto` on const and reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242449/c11-standard-ref-for-action-of-auto-on-const-and-reference-types)

```
auto rvr_a = std::move(f); // Foo&& or is it Foo?
```

It's just `Foo`.  So this is the same as:

```
Foo rvr_a = std::move(f); // Foo&& or is it Foo?
```

But note this will still call move constructor if there is one.

Comment: Would `auto&& rvr_b = std::move(f)` call the move constructor?

Comment: @ronag No. The net effect is a reference binding.

Comment: @ronag: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657708/c11-the-range-based-for-statement-range-init-lifetime